# What are best practices for coding up MIP models?

Tags: modeling

When coding an application involving a MIP, what are the best practices I should follow? In particular, I mean:

1. Domain-specific language (GAMS, AMPL) or General purpose (Python, C#)?
2. Structure of the code: should it just be one long list of adding variables, constraints and callbacks or how should it be organized?
3. Are there like “example projects”, where I can see how it is done?

Comment: Are you referring to academic contexts or application in practice?

Comment: In general: I think the thinking about “applications” is industry-specific, but any hint towards good coding practices is appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you are asking. Do you mean formulating the MIP? coding the MIP in a modeling language? a solver API? coding the application that *uses* the MIP? It would be great if you can make your question a bit more specific. Thanks!

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 Good comment. That's much better than downvoting and voting to close, which in my opinion has been much too common a practice so far on this forum.

Comment: Updated the question @LarrySnyder610 , is it specific enough now?

Comment: Not really. :) It's really broad. There are tons of different reasons why one might choose a modeling language (GAMS etc.) vs. Python (etc.); tons of ways to organize one's code; and tons of examples online. Suggestions: (1) If you want answers to all 3 of these questions, ask them as 3 separate questions. That way, you can accept individual answers (and people can up-/down-vote individual answers) -- otherwise, what happens if someone gives a single answer that's awesome for #1 but horrible for #2?

Comment: (2) For question #1, be specific about what kinds of problems you are trying to solve and ask which approach is more suited to that type of problem, and why. (3) For question #2, again ask which approach is best suited to your particular needs; but this question IMO is really hard to answer because everyone has their own personal coding style. Focusing on "best practices" might help make it more concrete? (4) For question #3, there are lots of examples of optimization code online; is there a particular type of example you are looking to see?

Comment: And if you're just asking, how can I get started in writing modeling/optimization code, then ask that instead.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/guides/rules-of-ml/ can be readily adapted to OR / analytics projects

Comment: @CMichael I just read through the rules and in my opinion nothing but rule 16 is applicable to OR. The article, while it seems very sensible for ML practitioners, does not answer questions such as (a) what to do with variables/constraints etc? (B) how best to inject heuristics into a problem from a coding perspective etc.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 That’s fair, I’ll sit down and write a more concrete version of my question in the coming days. In essence I am asking: given a MIP, are there best practices to convert that into good code. I think there are some underlying rules that make a lot of sense in my experience, but I would like to hear from others what they have in mind.

Comment: @Richard Sounds great. This will make a great question, in the end. If you want to close this question in the meantime, you can; otherwise, you can leave it up and folks can see the status from these comments.

Answer (score 2):

***Revised answer after OP's edit***

If you are interested in a high-level framework on how to start the coding process from reading your initial inputs, how to best handle writing the optimization model, how to handle different solvers, and so on, then I suggest to check out [this](https://github.com/ekhoda/optimization-tutorial) GitHub repository.

I put that together mainly for teaching purposes. It has an object-oriented design in Python with a simple optimization example to follow for different solvers (Cplex, Gurobi for commercial and PuLP as the open-source package) and I think it's a good starting point, especially for question #2.